# Jupyter Server process terminated before the initialization completed

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

I have been using JupyterLab Desktop on a mac for the past few weeks and it has been working fine until today. I am not quite sure exactly what I've done, but whenever I attempt to open the program and create a new notebook or new session I get the following error messages (see attached image). Any thoughts?[image]